# How to use master theorem to solve $T(n)=4T(n/8) + \sqrt n (\log_2 n)^2$

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I want to solve the following using master theorem.

> $T(n)=4T(n/8) + \sqrt n (\log_2 n)^2$

I have: $a=4, b=8,f(n)=\sqrt n (\log_2 n)^2$

I calculate $n^{log_b a} = n^{\log_8 4} = n^{2/3}$

I compare $f(n)=\sqrt n (\log_2 n)^2$ with $n^{2/3}$, and see that $f(n)$ grows faster than $n^{2/3}$.

So using master theorem, rule 3,  $f(n) \in \Omega (n^{2/3 +some \ c})$, which means $T(n) \in \Theta(f(n))$

---

But I guess this isn't correct, according to [this master theorem calculator tool](https://www.nayuki.io/page/master-theorem-solver-javascript) I used to check my answer.

Where's the mistake?

Comment: It might help if you would describe your reasoning that $f(n)$ grows faster than $n^{2/3}$. It doesn't.

Comment: @RickDecker thanks this was a stupid mistake indeed!